# Show mail icon only if sql data is available

Tags: php, html

I want, that in my search the mail icon only appears, if a mail adress is available in the result of the search.

Right now my code looks like this:

```
echo "<a href='mailto:".$results['eMail']."' style='color:#6264a7;'><img src='images/mail.jpg'/></a>";
```

Comment: Can you show the code which checks if the mail address is on the database?

Comment: So, use an `if` statement before you echo. What have you tried?

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (I see no SQL in the question. Is the answer expected to contain SQL?)

Comment: right now there is no if statement or anything else. I just show the result. Thats why I ask, how I can check if the result is empty and give out the code if its not.

Comment: yes there is a sql request which will displayed in the result variabe

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.) Also show us your current SQL query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood, this should be all you need:

```
if (!empty($results['eMail'])) echo "<a href='mailto:".$results['eMail']."' style='color:#6264a7;'><img src='images/mail.jpg'/></a>";
```

Documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: thats exactly what I was asking for. Thanks!

Only one closing bracket was missing

Comment: No problem - next time though, you could just google "php check if empty" and get the idea, it's a pretty common / trivial requirement.